# Sed add text after match

Tags: sed

I have a xmltv file that has the following style lines for program start/stop times

```
<programme start="20150914003000" stop="20150914020000" channel="Noor TV">
```

I want to add +0000 to the end of the start/stop time like the following

```
<programme start="20150914003000 +0000" stop="20150914020000 +0000" channel="Noor TV">
```

I am using windows sed and got this far

```
sed -r "/<programme start=\"/ s/^([0-9]{14})/\1 +0000/g" < "xml.xml" > "xml2.xml"
```

its giving me sed cant read >: invalid argument
in the dos windows I can see its adding the +0000 but not writing the new file
I know its something dumb but I just cant figure it out.
thks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sed -r "/<programme start=/ s/^([0-9]{14})/\1 +0000/g" "xml.xml" > "xml2.xml"
```

or (posix version)

```
sed "/<programme start=/ s/^([0-9]\{14\})/\1 +0000/g" "xml.xml" > "xml2.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cat xml.xml
<programme start="20150914003000" stop="20150914020000" channel="Noor TV">
$sed -r 's/start="([0-9]{14})" stop="([0-9]{14})"/start="\1 +0000" stop="\2 +0000"/' xml.xml >xml2.xml
$cat xml2.xml
<programme start="20150914003000 +0000" stop="20150914020000 +0000" channel="Noor TV">
```

had tried it by online linux

Answer (score -1):

The first < needs a backslash, not a forward slash.

```
sed -r "\<programme start=\"/ s/^([0-9]{14})/\1 +0000/g" < "xml.xml" > "xml2.xml"
```